# Chromecast CAF freeze issue on Gen#1 devices

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, caf-receiver-sdk

CAF receiver from Chromecast Gen#1 freeze while Chromecast Gen#2 is working just fine for the same piece of content.

Even chrome://inspect is not throwing any error. From the logs you can see, video is in progress and progress bar is spinning on the receiver side. After a while it just ends the session on receiver side automatically while sender is keep showing progress bar.

I am not sure what causes this behaviour, because I am not able to debug it properly from chrome://inspect logs because of no error.

If is something up with the stream or do i have to change on receiver side?